# How to make my file DropSouce be accepted by all targets that works with files?

Tags: delphi, interface, drag-and-drop, delphi-2009

I made a control that represents a list of files and I want to be able to drag the files from my control to other applications that work with files. I implemented the IDragSource interface (as shown below) but when I drag, the files are accepted only by windows explorer, other applications like Firefox, Yahoo Messenger, Photoshop... do not accept my files. What have I done wrong ? I have a feeling that IDataObject is not set correctly and I'm afraid I have to implemet it myself... and this is a very coplicated job for me to do because I just started to work with interfaces.

Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ActiveX, ShlObj;

type
  TMyControl = class(TMemo, IDropSource)
  private
   function QueryContinueDrag(fEscapePressed:BOOL; grfKeyState:Longint):HResult; stdcall;
   function GiveFeedback(dwEffect:Longint):HResult; stdcall;
   procedure DoDragAndDrop;
   function GetFileListDataObject:IDataObject;
  protected
   procedure MouseMove(Shift:TShiftState; X,Y:Integer); override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    MyMemo:TMyControl;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{TMyControl}

function TMyControl.QueryContinueDrag(fEscapePressed:BOOL; grfKeyState:Longint):HResult;
begin
 if fEscapePressed then Result:=DRAGDROP_S_CANCEL
  else if (grfKeyState and (MK_LBUTTON or MK_RBUTTON) = 0) then Result:=DRAGDROP_S_DROP
   else Result:=S_OK;
end;

function TMyControl.GiveFeedback(dwEffect:Longint):HResult;
begin
 Result:=DRAGDROP_S_USEDEFAULTCURSORS;
end;

procedure TMyControl.DoDragAndDrop;
var AllowedEffects,DropEffect:Longint;
    DataObj:IDataObject;
begin
 AllowedEffects:=DROPEFFECT_COPY;
 DataObj:=GetFileListDataObject;
 if DataObj <> nil then
  DoDragDrop(DataObj, self, AllowedEffects, DropEffect);
end;

function TMyControl.GetFileListDataObject:IDataObject;
var Desktop:IShellFolder;
    Attr,Eaten:ULONG;
    Count,x:Integer;
    Pidls:array of PItemIDList;
begin
 Result:=nil;
 Count:=Lines.Count;
 if Count<1 then Exit;
 if Failed(SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop)) then Exit;
 SetLength(Pidls,Count);
 for x:=0 to Count-1 do Pidls[x]:=nil;
 try
  for x:=0 to Count-1 do
   if Failed(Desktop.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, PWideChar(Lines[x]), Eaten, Pidls[x], Attr)) then Exit;
  Desktop.GetUIObjectOf(0, Count, Pidls[0], IDataObject, nil, Result);
 finally
  for x:=0 to Count-1 do
   if Pidls[x]<>nil then CoTaskMemFree(Pidls[x]);
 end;
end;

procedure TMyControl.MouseMove(Shift:TShiftState; X,Y:Integer);
begin
 if ssLeft in Shift then DoDragAndDrop;
 inherited;
end;

//---------------------------------

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MyMemo:=TMyControl.Create(Form1);
 MyMemo.Parent:=Form1;
 MyMemo.Align:=alClient;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Are you files from the same folder or files can be located in different folders?

Comment: All my files are in the same folder.

Comment: There's a lot missing here. We can't see all of the code. An MCVE would mean we could be confident we know what your code is. Some indication of how the code fails would help. Also the details of your debugging. Presumably you've debugged with trace debugging?

Comment: Ok, I will try to make a MCVE and update my question, but you will see that there is nothing important in the rest of the code. How it fails ? Well, when I drag the files to the target area of an application that I know it can accept files (tested with explorer) the mouse pointer turns into the forbidden sign (that circle with a line in the middle) and if I dorp there, nothing happens.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at Anders Melander's Drag'n'Drop Suite. Look here: http://melander.dk/articles/dragdrop52released/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I updated my question with the MCVE. HeartWare, I've studied that code for 3 days and I still don't understand how it works, because it's very complex, but I don't give up :) That code works well but I want something simpler for my application, I just need a simple DropSource only for files...

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: I don't know what debugging should I do, because after I start the drag and drop with `DoDragDrop()` everything is done by the system...

Comment: I think your code is working fine i copy it as it is and fill the memo with some lines and it's work on all apps like paint,chrome,acdsee everything

Comment: That's strange. I don't know what to say. Here on my computer it's not working on all apps that it should...

Comment: You need trace debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you use incorrect call of Desktop.GetUIObjectOf. When you call SomeFolder.GetUIObjectOf items MUST be childs of SomeFolder. But in your case it is not true. Try something like this:

```
type
  PPItemIDList = ^PItemIDList;

function GetFileListDataObject(AParentWnd: HWND; const APath: string; AFileNames: TStrings): IDataObject;
var
  Desktop: IShellFolder;
  Eaten, Attr: ULONG;
  i: Integer;
  PathIDList: PItemIDList;
  PathShellFolder: IShellFolder;
  IDLists: PPItemIDList;
  IDListsSize: Integer;
  Pos: PPItemIDList;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if AFileNames.Count < 1 then Exit;

  if Failed(SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop)) then Exit;
  try
    Attr := 0;
    if Failed(Desktop.ParseDisplayName(AParentWnd, nil, PWideChar(APath), Eaten, PathIDList, Attr)) then Exit;
    try
      if Failed(Desktop.BindToStorage(PathIDList, nil, IShellFolder, PathShellFolder)) then Exit;
      try
        IDListsSize := SizeOf(PItemIDList) * AFileNames.Count;
        GetMem(IDLists, IDListsSize);
        try
          ZeroMemory(IDLists, IDListsSize);
          Pos := IDLists;
          for i := 0 to AFileNames.Count - 1 do
            begin
              Attr := 0;
              if Failed(PathShellFolder.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, PWideChar(AFileNames[i]), Eaten, Pos^, Attr)) then Exit;
              Inc(Pos);
            end;
          PathShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf(0, AFileNames.Count, IDLists^, IDataObject, nil, Result);
        finally
          Pos := IDLists;
          for i := 0 to AFileNames.Count - 1 do
            begin
              if Assigned(Pos^) then
                CoTaskMemFree(Pos^);
              Inc(Pos);
            end;
          FreeMem(IDLists);
        end;
      finally
        PathShellFolder := nil;
      end;
    finally
      CoTaskMemFree(PathIDList);
    end;
  finally
    Desktop := nil;
  end;
end;
```